# Syntax for a function in order to get post's title in JSON encoded response

Tags: functions, ajax, json

I use the following code in functions.php in order to obtain all the images attached to a post so I can retrieve them via AJAX.

```
<?php
function get_all_images($post_id=0, $size='bigger', $attributes='') {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    if ($post_id<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
    if ($images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
        $response = '';
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            $tranparent=get_template_directory_uri();
            $response .= '<img src="'.$tranparent.'/images/transparent.gif" data-original="'.$attachment[0].'" alt="" class="imarge" />';
        }
    die( json_encode( $response ) );
}?>
```

What I would like to do is to add a `<h2 class="titles">Title of the post</h2>` in the response before all the images.

So I tried this:

```
<?php
function get_all_images($post_id=0, $size='bigger', $attributes='') {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    if ($post_id<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
    if ($images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
        $img = '';
        $title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $response = '<h2 class="titles">'.$title.'</h2>'.$img.'';
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            $tranparent=get_template_directory_uri();
            $img .= '<img src="'.$tranparent.'/images/transparent.gif" data-original="'.$attachment[0].'" alt="" class="imarge" />';
        }
    die( json_encode( $response ) );
}?>
```

I now get the post's title but not the images anymore. Any idea?

Comment: Change $img to $response

Comment: This is a simple error with variable name confusion. Close voting as too-localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the title to the response, not replace the response with the title.  Like this:

```
<?php
function get_all_images($post_id=0, $size='bigger', $attributes='') {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    if ($post_id<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
    if ($images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
            $title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $response = '<h2 class="titles">'.$title.'</h2>';
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            $tranparent=get_template_directory_uri();

            $response .= '<img src="'.$tranparent.'/images/transparent.gif" data-original="'.$attachment[0].'" alt="" class="imarge" />';
        }
    die( json_encode( $response ) );
}?>
```

**Update**

Corrected to add it before the loop.

Comment: This produce the title to be added several times if there are several images attached to the post. I wanted the title to appear once per post. I added the solution. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I noticed the mistake, and fixed it, a moment after I posted the answer.  Glad you had figured it out, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function get_all_images($post_id=0, $size='bigger', $attributes='') {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
    if ($post_id<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
    if ($images = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))
        $img = '';
        $title = get_the_title($post_id);
        $response = '<h2 class="titles">'.$title.'</h2>';
        foreach($images as $image) {
            $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, $size);
            $tranparent=get_template_directory_uri();
            $response .= '<img src="'.$tranparent.'/images/transparent.gif" data-original="'.$attachment[0].'" alt="" class="imarge" />';
        }
    die( json_encode( $response ) );
}?>
```